# DropDownList in kendo grid control (by ClientTemplate)

Tags: c#, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I need to make behavor for ClientTemplate like we have for EditorTemplateName.
So I want to make something like this:

Template:

```
@(
     Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
            .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["ExamResults"])
                .Template("#:Value# #:Text#")
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .DataValueField("Value")
            .Events(e => e
                .Change("examResultOnDropDownChange")
                .Open("examResultOnOpen"))
 )
```

And adding column into grid: `.EditorTemplateName("ExamResultGridForeignKey")`

but I want to: `.ClientTemplate("ExamResultGridForeignKey")`
or something like that (but it doesnt work):

```
.ClientTemplate(
                Html.Kendo()
                    .DropDownList()
                    .Name("#=Id#")
                    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["ExamResults"])
                    .Template("#:Value# #:Text#")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
 )
```

All that I need to make field with DropDownList in not editable mode (when we display value) looks like editable DropDownList.

Answer (score 1):

This is how my dropdown list is being rendered. IsInForecast is a bool field. All the If else is doing is having the correct ddl value (true/false) selected based on the value of the IsInForecast property. You're gonna have to tweak it to your needs.

```
columns.Bound(m => m.IsInForecast).Title("Is Forecasted").ClientTemplate(

   "# if (IsInForecast == true) { #" +

                          "<select id='#= OrderId #' onchange=save('#= OrderId #'); style='Width: 80px; color: 'navy' > " +
                            "<option id='yes' selected value='1'>Yes</option>" +
                            "<option id='no' value='0'>No</option>" +

                            "</select>" +
                     "# } else { #" +
                          "<select id='#= OrderId #' onchange=save('#= OrderId #'); style='Width: 80px; color: 'navy' > " +
                            "<option id='yes'  value='1'>Yes</option>" +
                            "<option id='no' selected value='0'>No</option>" +
                         "# } #" 
            );
```

Where you see `"<select id='#= OrderId #'` that is setting the ddl ID field to so you know which dropdownlist/record you are editing. `onchange=save('#= OrderId #');` is calling a JS function that passes the model property OrderId to the method. To get the selected value of correct ddl you just changed you can do this.

```
save(orderId) function{
  var ddl = # + orderId;
  var getSelectedValue = $(ddl).val();
}
```

This will render a standard DDL. You can check out the documentation here

```
 http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom.html
```

Comment: Yestaday I tried to make some Extensions methods on Generic parameters on GridColumnFactory<TModel>. But Ive got an error (Kendo cant parse they own MVVM, if I try to make Name parameter with that template '#=Id#')...

Comment: So now I think that your way is the only one. To not generate JS, but write it by hands.