# adding button on column template of kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am building an app using MVC using Jquery(KendoGrid) for displaying data, everything was working fine as per requirement, later we planned to add extra column with button present on each row of the grid, sounds simple, but tried number of ways to add into the application, getting error message "undefined 'node' ..... ", so i had no other options rather than posting here, if any one could able to help me in this will be appreciative, and i used column template on jquery kendo grid thanks

**scenario**

onclick of that button in specified row it should carry "**ID**(as shown below)" and redirect to "**ActionResult**" Controller, where I can further code as per my requirement

**code(part of the code)**

```
columns: [
                { field: "ID", Title: "ID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },

                { field: "RowID", Title: "RowID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },

                { field: "BillNumber", Title: "BillNumber", filterable: false, sortable: false,hidden:true },

                { field: "ServiceName", Title: "ServiceName",width:600 },

                { field: "ServiceStatus", Title: "ServiceStatus", width: 150 }
// Creating template column

               , {
                   field: "Action", title: "Is Action", template: "<input type=\"checkbox\"    #= Action ? checked='checked' : '' #  class=\"check_row\"/> ", editable: false,

                  // field: "Action",title: "Preview ", template: '<input type="button" class="info" name="info" value="Info" style="height: 26px; margin: 0px 2px; min-width: 64px;" />',                       

    headerTemplate: '<label>  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>Print All</label>', filterable: false, sortable: false, width: 100,                     
               }
```

currently I am able to generate checkbox in column, what i need is one more column with button(same as checkbox in each row)

Manjuboyz

Comment: Check out my answer to the following post, I am displaying a dropdown in every column, you should be able to manipulate the code to add a button instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217890/dropdownlist-in-kendo-grid-control-by-clienttemplate/23226834#23226834

Comment: Hi C Sharper

Thanks for your reply, but I am not using "columns.bound" or "client Template", I don't want to edit any of my code(since it is working as per my requirement), please suggest code which I can edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining a button in a cell is pretty simple... basically you were doing it right.

Example: Define a column as:

```
columns: [
    ...
    {
        title: "Preview ", 
        template: '<input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Info" />',                       
        headerTemplate: '<label>  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>Print All</label>', 
        filterable: false, 
        sortable: false, 
        width: 100                     
    }
]
```

Define the `template` as an `input` of type `button`. If you want it to look like a Kendo UI button add `k-button` class to it.

Then, you can bind a `click` handler doing:

```
$(".info").on("click", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    ...
});
```

Where `item` contains all the data corresponding to the row that you clicked the button.

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/m8fsv/1/

**EDIT:** If what you need is to control / decide showing one or the other, you should change the template to something like:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-template">
    # if (showButton) { #
    <input type="checkbox" #= data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\"/>
    # } else { #
    <input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Info" />
    # } #
</script>
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m8fsv/12/

Comment: Hi OnaBai, Thank you for your Reply, I believe I even tried this step, but it is not generating one more column(i need both checkbox and button), i tried your way and this error popups in IE "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.  "

Comment: OR To Everyone, I have one requirement in my mind, i don't know it can be done or not,if can be done then I am all set to go. Instead of getting different column of checkbox and button, can i able to have single column with button and checkbox(either any one based on condition) like on same grid some rows might have only checkbox or only button but not both, on select of "printall"(headertemplate) it should get only the values of checkbox not the button,please let me know if it is possibble, Thanks

Comment: If I comment Checkbox code then enable the button code which you have provided then there is not error and it generates a button column!!! but when both checkbox and button is Uncommented then it generates error as above(basically acts like only any one column is allowed not both), Am I doing any wrong ??? if needed willing to share more code about this, Thanks

Comment: Not problem having both (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m8fsv/12/) the only question is that if `Action` is not received, you should check for `data.Action` and not simply `Action` (`<input type=\"checkbox\" #= data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\"/>`)

Comment: ,if I replace my Checkbox template code to your fiddle, it shows only checkbox row, not button ?? and about my requirement, in a row it should have either checkbox or button (not both) like first row only button, second and third only checkbox and so on based on any condition ?? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is my last JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m8fsv/12/) not showing both? As I've said you need to change your template for asking for `data.Action` and not only `Action`, did you change this? Which is "your template"?

Comment: this is what i changed as per you said, and code changed on fiddle,  {
            title: "Preview ", 
            template: '<input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Info" />',                       
            field: "Action", title: "Is Action", template: "<input type=\"checkbox\"    #= data.Action ? checked='checked' : '' #  class=\"check_row\"/> ", editable: false,  
            filterable: false, 
            sortable: false, 
            width: 100                     
        }, have used "data.Action" but in fiddle it shows only checkbox

Comment: ,fiddle worked, thanks :), about my last requirement , can I able to get only checkbox or button based on any condition ?? what I am doing is, if I select check box then click on button(not the button on grid) it should create PDF file(which is working), but if i click a button which is on row, it should display only file (like preview of file) before creating it into PDF  ?? understood

Comment: Of course you can show one or the other. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m8fsv/24/

Comment: thanks for your posts, it might sound odd but have to ask, where should i use HTML code from fiddle into CSHTML(view)!! and as per your fiddle code, this is what i needed,hope everything goes fine :)

Comment: i have used your suggested code, there is few minor issues i am facing, first "button click event" is not triggering, it triggers in fiddle but when i used on my code, it wont do anything, i want to redirect to controller onclick of that button, i even used debugger, but still its not reaching there, any idea,     $(".info").on('click', function () {
            debugger;
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var item = Grid.dataItem(row);

            window.location.href = '/Login/FreeText?profileID=' + rowIDs + '&amp;billid=' + billID;

          
        });

Comment: thanks for your help, could you please use last fiddle on answer page?? so that I can accept it as answer ,Thanks again

Comment: please review this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820837/disable-enable-the-checkbox-in-kendo-grid-based-on-column-value" and let me know what should i do to get it work ??

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks this helps , But can i add a button in Kendo Grid that comes from a Different Controller ?

Comment: Sorry @EnriqueGil, what do you mean by a "button that comes from a different controller"? buttons are HTML, what is coming from a different controller?

Comment: @OnaBai here is my post question sir , thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074670/button-inside-a-kendo-grid-with-different-controller-onload