# Disable/Enable the checkbox in kendo grid based on column Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid all working good, now I got new requirement i.e. last column i have checkbox and just to that previous column I have a status column,

if that text value is "CERTIFIED" only then that specific row checkbox should be enabled, if the text is not 'CERTIFIED' it should disable the checkbox of that row,and should not allow to check that checkbox using jquery,  I have attached pic of kendogrid I have, which might help for any suggestions

**CODE**

**THESE ARE MY COLUMNS OF MY KENDO GRID**

```
, columns: [
            { field: "ResultFormatID", Title: "ResultFormatID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "ID", Title: "ID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "RowID", Title: "RowID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "BillNumber", Title: "Bill Number", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "ServiceName", Title: "Service Name", width: 600 },
            { field: "Status", Title: "Service Status", width: 150 }
             , {
               template: $("#template").html(),
               headerTemplate: '<label>  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>Download</label>', filterable: false, sortable: false, width: 100,
           }
         ]
```

**THIS IS MY INDIVIDUAL ROW CHECKBOX**

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-template">
   #if(ResultFormatID != 3) { #   
   <input type="checkbox" #= data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\"/>
   # } else { #
<input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Preview" />
   # } #
```

**UPDATED**

**THIS IS MY CHECKALL FUNCTION**(and what i did to uncheck)

```
 $("#checkAll").on('click', function (e) {
         debugger;

        var $cb = $(this);
        var checked = $cb.is(':checked');
        var grid = $('.Grid_table').data('kendoGrid');

        grid.table.find("tr").find("td:last input").attr("checked", checked);           


        var items = $(".Grid_table").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
       var status = item.ServiceStatus;

            if (status == "Result Certified ") {
              grid.table.find("tr").find("td:last input").attr("checked", checked);
            }
            else {

                grid.table.find("tr").find("td:last input").prop("checked",false);
            }
     if (!checked) {
            // debugger;
            $(".Grid_table").data("kendoGrid").clearSelection();
        }

    });

});
```

**UPDATE 2**

now as per your code, everything works fine and I am able to uncheck the not certified row, i am facing a problem with below code, if atleast single checkbox is not checked it disabled the button which is used to download the PDF file, now if i select all checkbox and clicked on that button download, it is disabled now!! but if i uncheck any one row out of like 10 rows, then download enables and used to download the file.

if I disable the last 3 lines  of below code, it helps in enabling the button to click, but i need to unselect atleast single check box to work, if not it will disabled, what am i doing wrong ??

```
 $(function () {
         //debugger;            
        var checkboxes = $(':checkbox:not(#checkAll)').click(function (event) {
            $('#btn_Print').prop("disabled", checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 0);
        });
        $('#checkAll').click(function (event) {
            checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
            $('#btn_Print').prop("disabled", !this.checked)
        });
    });
```

IF

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that what you need is controlling if the `input` field of `type="checkbox"` is `disabled`. So you should defined the template as follow:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-template">
   #if(ResultFormatID != 3) { #   
   <input type="checkbox" #= data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\" #= data.Status == 'Certified' ? disabled='disabled' : "" #/>
   # } else { #
<input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Preview" />
   # } #
</script>
```

I.e: add the condition of `data.Status == 'Certified' ? disabled='disabled' : ""`

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfk3Q/

**EDIT**: Changes required when clicking on headers check box would be changing its implementation for checking only those cells that are not disabled. Something like:

```
$('.check_row:not(:disabled)', grid.tbody).prop('checked', true);
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfk3Q/3/

Comment: Thanks for reply @OnaBai, this thing I already fixed it with respect to condition, have one small question, the reason I needed that check box to be disabled because that row shouldn't to be checked by user, but if i choose the header template "Select All" it selects everything including disabled one, i don't need that, i need only those rows which are status is enabled, i have attached pic above, please verify it if possible

Comment: I would recommend you to change `selectAll` code to do not select those that are disabled, that's pretty easy to control in jQuery.

Comment: Check my **EDIT** with proposed implementation of the function for checking all that are not disabled.

Comment: Yep, it seems easy, even code is very simple when i searched, but after implementing it is not changing its status, above i have shared my "checkAll" code, with condition, the status value shows correct, but when it goes to loop to uncheck it is not checking, could you able to find me what's wrong in that

Comment: Thanks for your code, I need certified to be "Enabled" and not certified to be "disabled" how can i negate the condition in template ?? along with that I have implemented you code, but select all still checks the disabled row too!!!

Comment: Change the order in the check from `data.Status == 'Certified' ? disabled='disabled' : ""` to `data.Status == 'Certified' ? "" : disabled='disabled'` Check http://jsfiddle.net/Hfk3Q/7/

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, I am not bugging you much, I have one last clarification, which is updated(2), after implementing your code, everything goes solid but except above, if it able to look into it, that will be great

Comment: The problem is in the first part of your code. You call `checkboxes` all the checkboxes that are not the one in the header (by the way, that's not the most efficient way of computing it) and then, when `checkAll` is clicked, you use this list (all the checkboxes in the body of the table) for enabling it. So you end-up enabling everything. Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/Hfk3Q/9/

Comment: Hi Onabai, I need on favor, for the same Kendo UI grid, i want do disable the Kendo Grid hover property, when i over into the Grid header it shades into grey , i dont wanted to change color , so Please can you suggest how to fix this,

Comment: .k-grid th.k-header,
.k-grid-header {
    background-color:#17937A;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    color:#D2E2DB;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-left:none;
    font-size:14px;
} this is the property of the header, how can i fix not to change color or position when hovered ??

Comment: Hi Onabai, Actually I found the answer which I asked for :-) i just used hover property for k-grid.